# Python 3.4: module : winreg windows registry reading

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, winreg

I am able read windows registry `SOFTWARE\\Python` but not able to read `SOFTWARE\\ORACLE` My test code is below am I missing anything

```
from winreg import *

def pathExists(hkey, regPath):
    try:
        reg = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regPath)
    except WindowsError:
        print("************ 111 WindowsError occured")
        return False
    CloseKey(reg)
    return True


oraclePath = "SOFTWARE\\ORACLE"
pythonPath = "SOFTWARE\\Python"
print("--------------python-----------------")  
print("Test path exist SOFTWARE\Python")
if pathExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pythonPath):
    print("Success : Test path exist ")
else:
    print("Failed : Test path NOT exist ")
print("--------------Orale-----------------")    
if pathExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, oraclePath):
    print("Success : Test path exist ")
else:
    print("Failed : Test path NOT exist ")
```

Ouput

```
--------------python-----------------
Test path exist SOFTWARE\Python
Success : Test path exist 
--------------Orale-----------------
************ 111 WindowsError occured
Failed : Test path NOT exist
```

Comment: Probably you're using 32-bit Python, for which Windows redirects `HKLM\SOFTWARE`  to the 32-bit software registry, `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`.

Comment: To read the 64-bit software registry you can use the optional `access` argument, e.g. `access=winreg.KEY_READ | winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY`.

Comment: Thanks!  I have installed Windows X86-64 MSI Installer (3.3.2).  It worked.